# Why does my mobile website look bad when zoomed out on mobile?

Tags: html, css, web, mobile

I'm building a business website for a company a friend and I came up with, but the mobile version of it is terrible if you zoom out on a phone.the website is B.C Infinity Contracts (https://bcinfinitycontracts .ca).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
      
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Welcome to B.C Infinity Contract Solutions</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Let B.C Infinity Contract Solutions be your choice for landscaping, lawn work, and odd jobs in the okanagan."/>
      <meta name="keywords" content="landscaping, odd jobs, painting, lawn Care, penticton,south okanagan"/>
      <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" /> 



@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {


#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
padding-right: 0;
float: right;    
}

#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul:last-child {
display: none;
}
 

}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px){
 .imgresize{
    width:95%;
    height:95%;  
    }
}

 @media (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px){
 .imgresize{
    width:25%;
    height:25%;  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question with many answers. You could spend some time searching stackoverflow for an answer or view "mobile development best practices" to get some ideas. Places like codepen is great to get code snippets to learn from as well.

Try updating your question to be more specific and technical in order to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your meta tag for viewport to the following. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Next you'll want to modify some of your CSS to better work with the responsive design.

Specifically on the website you have a logo that isn't responsive.
`<img alt="logo.jpg" class="center-block" src="images/logo.png">`

You can make this more responsive by adding some CSS to it.

try

```css
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1028px;
```

This should give you a base to work on your responsive design.